# Problem by Access to ubuntu shared folder

Tags: 13.10, sharing

I shared a folder in ubuntu and it installed samba service for make it work. then from another ubuntu system i can see that shared folder in network place. but when i want to open it, it asks me username, domain, password. I know the username and password. but it doesn't accept it? there is not any joined domain what should i put for domain? i tried workgroup but nothing changed!!!

Answer (score 0):

Install the package libpam-smbpass if it is not installed yet. Samba requires this package to synchronize the users on the pc that do the hosting to samba users. I had the same issue and this resolved it. Just remember to restart the samba services after installing that package.